# How can I insert a special french character in a bibtex cite-key?

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to use some tricks in order to have the correct characters in my bibliography :

```
  @book{Anzieu1981,
  author = {Anzieu, Didier},
  title = {Le corps de l'{\oe}uvre.%some tricks like this one. Essais psychanalytiques sur le travail créateur},
  publisher = {Gallimard},
  address = {Paris, France},
  year = {1981},
  }
```

But I have an issue with a cite-key :

```
  @misc{Ricœur1955,
  author = {Ricoeur, Paul},
  title = {La parole est mon royaume},
  number = {4},
  url = {http://leportique.revues.org/263},
  year = {1955},
  }
```

When I run my .bib file with Texmaker (on a Mac), that character : œ isn't compiled correctly and I can't resolve myself to use the following one : oe. How can I fix that issue ?

Comment: Is your `tex` file encoded in UTF-8? Or ISO?

Comment: No, it doesn't work with UTF-8 or ISO. I have to use applemac/inputenc instead. And it works... except for that case.

Comment: Don't use special characters in citation keys. That's all.

Comment: Just call him Rick :o). But you can write `author={Ricœur, Paul}`and `title={Le corps de l'œuvre…}` if you use `biber`.

Comment: You can try with `bibtex8` or `bibtexu` instead of `bibtex`

Comment: Why do you *have* to use applemac? It should be forbidden these days…

Comment: In addition to use `bibtexu` you have to compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`

Comment: Why do you want the oe diphthong in the key and just a plain oe in the actual name?  If anything (and it's kind of a big if) that's backwards: no one sees or cares what the bibkey is, whereas it does matter that the output is correct.  So, while I like the name+date bibkey approach (e.g., `ricoeur1955`) for bibkeys, you could more easily have `a98soidfha` as the bibkey than you could have `author = {RIcoeru, Pauli}` as the field entry....

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use non ASCI character in bibtex entry keys if one compiles with `lualatex` or `xelatex` and either `bibtex8` or `bibtexu`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Ricœur1955,
  author = {Ricœur, Paul},
  title = {La parole est mon royaume},
  number = {4},
  url = {http://leportique.revues.org/263},
  year = {1955},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Ricœur \cite{Ricœur1955} \verb|\cite{Ricœur1955}|

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

Compiling  the MWE with `lualatex + bibtexu + lualatex + lualatex` produces

[image]

Comment: In fact, it works fine when I use Times as my \setmainfont command. It doesn't work when I set that command : \setmainfont{Minion Pro}. Even when I encode my file in UTF-8 with Xelatex. Does it mean that the problem is due to Minion Pro ?

Comment: For me it works with Minion Pro using `\usepackage{MinionPro}`. I have installed it using Font Pro framework.

Comment: Do you work on a mac ? May you post your preamble, please, so I could try to see if it works on mine ?

Comment: OK. I've modified the label's name of Ricœeur. I called it Ric1955 and it works fine.

Comment: The MWE is in the post, for Minion Pro, just add `\usepackage{MinionPro}` to the preamble. I did just after losing `fontspec`. With `lualatex` or `xelatex` and `bibtexu` there is no need to change the key.