# What is valid as a BibLaTeX entry key?

Tags: biblatex, zotero, pandoc-citeproc

What characters are valid in a biblatex entry key?

I'm asking because [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) will export entry keys with `<i>foo</i>` in them, and [pandoc-citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc) doesn't like that. But I don't know whether Zotero is too permissive, or pandoc-citeproc is too strict.

This is the error that pandoc-citeproc generates with an entry key like that:

```
pandoc-citeproc: "stdin" (line 10918, column 2):
unexpected "A"
expecting "c", "C", "p", "P", "s" or "S"
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Text/CSL/Input/Bibtex.hs:113:32 in pandoc-citeproc-0.10.4-BdOyQb33rzG2TMOLj4Fbp9:Text.CSL.Input.Bibtex
pandoc: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
Filter returned error status 1
```

Comment: `biblatex` accepts `<i>foo</i>` as a bibkey with Biber and BibTeX as a backend. So the problem must lie elsewhere. In general you should try and use only ASCII letters and numbers as well as a few special characters such as `-`, `.`, `:`, `_`. Avoid non-ASCII letters (`ä`, `ß`, `É`) - even if they might work if you use an engine with full Unicode support and Biber. You should also avoid commas as well as braces (curly and otherwise).

Comment: For future reference, we removed html markup in citekeys in bibtex export from Zotero a while ago and it's an oversight that it remains in biblatex. We'll fix that, even if it may take a little time. See https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/comment/284813/#Comment_284813 for discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An entry key may contain `<`, `>` and `/` if you use `biblatex` no matter if you use the legacy BibTeX backend or Biber. So `<i>foo</i>` is acceptable as part of a entry key.

In general, however, it is a good idea to only use ASCII letters (lowercase `a-z` and uppercase `A-Z`; keep in mind that the names are case sensitive), digits and a few special characters such as `.`, `-`, `:`, `_`, `/`.

If you use a fully Unicode-aware TeX engine such as XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX your entry keys may also contain non-ASCII letters (with diacritics, from other scripts etc.) such as `é`, `ß`, `Ä`.

A key may never contain a comma (`,`) or braces or brackets (curly `{`, `}` or round `(`, `)`).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243729/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864