# Bibtex- can't get my citations to work

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I am trying to create my citations and I am really frustrated. Whenever I try to compile my `.bib` with BibTeX I get this error

> Process started
>
> I couldn't open file name `sample.aux'
>
> Process exited normally

When I try to cite something in my text with `\cite{}` I can see all my citations, but when I try to compile (pdflatex+bib(la)tex +pdflatex(x2)+ show pdf)
I get this message:

Process started

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: Project DLC.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
White space in argument---line 6 of file Project DLC.aux:
\citation{Grigoriadis : diss} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: Project_DLC-blx.bib
Database file #2: sample.bib
"{" immediately follows a field name---line 49 of file sample.bib :
year : {1978}, I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 53 of file sample.bib: 
@article{Grigoriadis : diss, I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 61 of file sample.bib: 
@article{Elmahdy : diss, I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Biblatex version: 3.8
(There were 4 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

I am also using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

and `\printbibliography` at the end of the doc.
I cant really understand what's going on so I could use some help!
Also here is the part that i want to cite, if that helps:

```
Οι θερμοτροπικοί με την σειρά τους διακρίνονται σε δύο κατηγορίες: Τους ραβδόμορφους υγρούς κρυστάλλους (ΡΥΚ) και τους δισκόμορφους υγρούς κρυστάλλους (ΔΥΚ) (Εικόνα 1). Στην παρόυσα εργασία θα ασχοληθούμε αποκλειστικά με τους θερμοτροπικούς ΔΥΚ.\cite{Grigoriadis diss}
```

Here is my `sample.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{Feng2009421,
author={Feng, X. and Marcon, V. and Pisula, W. and Hansen, M.R. and Kirkpatrick, J. and Grozema, F. and Andrienko, D. and Kremer, K. and Müllen, K.},
title={Towards high charge-carrier mobilities by rational design of the shape and periphery of discotics},
journal={Nature Materials},
year={2009},
volume={8},
number={5},
pages={421-426},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Grigoriadis20101403,
author={Grigoriadis, C. and Haase, N. and Butt, H.-J. and Müllen, K. and Floudas, C.},
title={Negative thermal expansion in discotic liquid crystals of nanographenes},
journal={Advanced Materials},
year={2010},
volume={22},
number={12},
pages={1403-1406},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Laschat20074832,
author={Laschat, S. and Baro, A. and Steinke, N. and Giesselmann, F. and Hägele, C. and Scalia, G. and Judele, R. and Kapatsina, E. and Sauer, S. and Schreivogel, A. and Tosoni, M.},
title={Discotic liquid crystals: From tailor-made synthesis to plastic electronics},
journal={Angewandte Chemie - International Edition},
year={2007},
volume={46},
number={26},
pages={4832-4887},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Sergeyev20071902,
author={Sergeyev, S. and Pisula, W. and Geerts, Y.H.},
title={Discotic liquid crystals: A new generation of organic semiconductors},
journal={Chemical Society Reviews},
year={2007},
volume={36},
number={12},
pages={1902-1929},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{C.N.R.RAO,
author={C.N.R.Rao and K.J.Rao},
title={Phase Transitions in Solids},
journal={McGraw-Hill, USA},
year{1978},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Grigoriadis diss,
author={Grigoriadis, C.},
title={Doctoral dissertation - Graphene discotic liquid crystals: self-assembly and dynamics},
journal={University of Ioannina},
year{2014},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Elmahdy diss,
author={Elmahdy, M.M.},
title={Doctoral dissertation - Self-assembly and Dynamics of Liquid Crystals},
journal={University of Ioannina},
year{2008},
hyphenation="english",
}

@ARTICLE{Sweicher,
author={Seweicher, G. and Olivier, Y. and Lemaur, V. and Geerts, Y.H.},
title={What Currently Limits Charge Carrier Mobility in Crystals
of Molecular Semiconductors?},
journal={Isr.J.Chem.},
year={2014},
volume={54},
pages={595-620},
hyphenation="english",
}


@ARTICLE{Takimiya20114347,
author={Takimiya, K. and Shinamura, S. and Osaka, I. and Miyazaki, E.},
title={Thienoacene-based organic semiconductors},
journal={Advanced Materials},
year={2011},
volume={23},
number={38},
pages={4347-4370},
hyphenation="english",
}
```

Comment: I know i've missed some '=' on my .bib and i corrected them but i still get the ''I couldn't open file name `sample.aux' ''

Comment: What you also get is a " White space in argument" when processing the `\cite{Grigoriadis diss}`. Looks like bibTeX doesn't like whitespace in its keys.

Comment: Yes thank you! it seems like that space was the problem.solved it both in the bib and the \cite{} 
It works now!
Case closed!

Comment: Indeed, you *must not* have spaces in keys, write `Grigoriadis:diss` or something similar instead of `Grigoriadis diss`. Same for `Elmahdy diss`. You forgot a `=` in `year{1978},` of `C.N.R.RAO`

Comment: With modern versions of `biblatex` you should use `backend=biber` instead of `backend=bibtex`. Simply change that option and tell your editor to run Biber for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Of course the errors in your `.bib` file still need correcting.

Comment: Consider allow to some program as Jabref to fix the keys for you automatically. This will save you of problems like duplicates keys, keys with spaces, not allowed characters, and inconsistent rules (some times with year, some times not ...) that make impossible remember/deduce the key without consulting  the .bib file.

Comment: @remco Do you want to type up a quick answer here, or do we close as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864?

Comment: I"d say make it a duplicate and close

Comment: @remco OK, done!