# Missing-\endcsname-error in citing the references

Tags: citing

Preamble

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Document body

```
Laboratory reflectance spectra of differentiated meteorites can be used
to identify indicate the rock-forming materials of asteroids at small
scales \cite{Gaffey} and \cite{Trigo-Rodríguez1}.
Over the years, more information such as physico-chemical
properties of asteroids and their reflective behavior were obtained
by much sensitive and precise spectrometers \cite{Dotto} and  \cite{Trigo-Rodríguez2}. \\
```

error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\IeC
l.120 ...cite{Gaffey} and \cite{Trigo-Rodríguez1}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage{movie15} \usepackage{cite}

Comment: At the moment my best guess is that the non-ASCII char `í` in `\cite{Trigo-Rodríguez1}` is problematic. Entry keys are mean to be internal names and must be reasonably safe. With a non-Unicode engine `í` is not reasonably safe. Change the key of `Trigo-Rodríguez1` to `Trigo-Rodriguez1` (with `i` instead of `í`) in both the `.bib` and `.tex` file and compile again.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The citation/entry keys in your `.bib` file should not contain non-ASCII chars such as `í` if you use a non-Unicode engine. The reason for that is that the keys are used as internal identifiers and so LaTeX must be able to handle them without them breaking easily.

Change `Trigo-Rodríguez1` and `Trigo-Rodríguez2` to

```
Trigo-Rodriguez1
```

and

```
Trigo-Rodriguez2
```

repectively, i.e. replace the `í` with `i` in the key in both your `.bib` and `.tex` file.

Related: [What characters are allowed to use as delimiters for BibTeX keys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864) and linked questions.