# Printing non-cited software in separate bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

Unfortunately I can't find quite a solution, hence this post.
I need to print a separate "References" section for software used in the article. This software obviously isn't cited anywhere in the text.
I am using **TexShop**, **biber** as a backend connected to **Zotero** with **better-bibtex**. The software (for example **RStudio**) can be either in my Zotero library or in a separate bib-file.
In the first bibliography, only software should be printed (for example with `category={software}`); in the second bibliography any works cited in the text should be printed.
I did not quite manage to do this yet, so I am happy for some help. Thank you!

Text from my preamble, indicating what I am working with:

```
\usepackage[
    style=chicago-authordate,
    backref=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backend=biber
    ]
    {biblatex}
    \renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} 
%replace the comma with a colon
    \usepackage{bibentry}
    \addbibresource[location=remote]{http://localhost:23119/better-bibtex/library?/1/library.biblatex} 
%Dynamic pull request with zotero; this is the link to the whole library

    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{files/software.biblatex}
        @Manual{,
            title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R, v1.1.463},
            author = {{RStudio Team}},
            organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
            address = {Boston, MA},
            year = {2016},
            url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
            keywords = {software},
            category = {software},
      }
    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{files/software.biblatex}
```

Then, I should print two bibliographies:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Data Sources}\label{DataSources}
\printbibliography[category=software]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography
```

EDIT:
I tried to strip everything that is not need to get to a minimal working example, using two sources, where one should be listed in the reference section, the other should be listed in the data sources section.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% INSTRUCTIONS FOR ARARA
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWE}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OPTIONS FOR BIBER
\usepackage[
    style=chicago-authordate,
    backref=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backend=biber
    ]
    {biblatex}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@software{rstudio,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},  
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
    version = {1.1.463},
    keyword = {software},
    }

@article{ullmann2010bit,
  title={Bit-vector algorithms for binary constraint satisfaction and subgraph isomorphism},
  author={Ullmann, Julian R},
  journal={Journal of Experimental Algorithmics (JEA)},
  volume={15},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2010},
  publisher={ACM},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a reference that should show up in the Reference section: \parencite[5]{ullmann2010bit}\\
I used RStudio; details can be found in the Data Sources section.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Data Sources}
\printbibliography[keyword={software},title={Data Sources}]

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography[notkeyword={software}]

\end{document}
```

EDIT2: I could also try to solve the problem by generating a bibliography in the desired format in Zotero (output as **RTF** or **HTML**) and then embed the HTML or RTF file in the desired section, where my software should show up (it is only going to be a handful or data sources, so exporting them manually from Zotero is feasible). I am using the **LuaLaTex** engine, if that helps with this (due to 'fontspec').

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there any chance you can complete the two code snippets to one, so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), that we can just copy, paste and run to see what you have so far. It is always a bit ... discouraging if we have to build working code from the snippets shown in the question, when it is quite certain that you have a working document at your end.

Comment: As far as I can see from the fragments shown so far you probably want `\printbibliography[keyword=software]` instead of `\printbibliography[category=software]`. `keywords` are set in the `.bib` file, `category`s in the TeX file and I can't see any code for the category in the TeX file. The `category = {software},` in the `.bib` file will be ignored.

Comment: Also an entry with empty entry key will crash Biber (or rather abort the Biber run with an error, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457685/35864): `@Manual{,` won't work, you need something like `@Manual{rstudio,` In case you don't want to cite the manual, but rather the (abstract) software itself, you can use the entry type `@software` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I added a MWE – without 'category', but 'keyword' instead, including a cite key. As I said, I use zotero which generates the citekeys – I don't really care where I will have to store the information about the software (Zotero or a separate file) as long as it prints the information in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible take at it. We employ the usual `\nocite{*}` to add all entries present in the bib file(s) to the bibliography, but then, we add all entries which are actually cited to the category `cited`. That should be enough, alongside the `keywords={software}`, to properly screen each of your bibliographies.

Note that I removed a couple of packages you loaded, with comments as to why. I've also fallen back to entrytype `misc` for your software entry, because `biblatex-chicago` threw me an error for it ("I can't find a driver for the entry type 'software' and there is no fallback driver either.").

```
\documentclass{article}

% you shouldn’t need this with lualatex...
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWE}

\usepackage[
    style=chicago-authordate,
    backref=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backend=biber
    ]
    {biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@misc{rstudio,
  title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
  author = {{RStudio Team}},
  organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
  address = {Boston, MA},
  year = {2016},
  url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  version = {1.1.463},
  keywords = {software},
}

@article{ullmann2010bit,
  title={Bit-vector algorithms for binary constraint satisfaction and subgraph isomorphism},
  author={Ullmann, Julian R},
  journal={Journal of Experimental Algorithmics (JEA)},
  volume={15},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2010},
  publisher={ACM},
}
\end{filecontents}

% no need with biblatex, and possibly incompatible with it, use \fullcite instead
% \usepackage{bibentry}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}
This is a reference that should show up in the Reference section: \parencite[5]{ullmann2010bit}\\
I used RStudio; details can be found in the Data Sources section.

\nocite{*}

% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Data Sources} % better use printbibliography’s options for that
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword={software},title={Data Sources}]

% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,category=cited,notkeyword={software}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted!