# Bibliography Errors: Empty

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texworks, jabref

I am using TeXWorks and running pdfLaTeX + MarkeIndex + BibTeX. I made my .bib file with the newest version of JabRef for PC. Here is my MWE:

```
 \documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\bibliography{/C:/Users/Ryan Schiller/Kannai}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> No pages of output.
>   Transcript written on "try it.log".
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> C:\Users\Ryan
>   Schiller\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log

But as you can see, I do have a .bib file:[image]

So I renamed the document to "tryit" without a space. Then I deleted my aux files. Then in command line I ran `pdflatex tryit.tex`, `pdflatex tryit.tex`,`biber tryit.tex`, `pdflatex tryit.tex`

But on the first run, I got the error:

> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10. (tryit.aux) LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: (biblatex) tryit (biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards. ) No pages of output. Transcript written on tryit.log

How do I get my references?

Comment: Don't add the same `.bib` file with `\addbibresource` and `\bibliography`, use only one of the two. I strongly prefer `\addbibresource`. Note that if you use `\addbibresource` you must include the file extension (`.bib`), but you must not include it when you use `\bibliography`. The MWE as shown will not produce any bibliography or citations because nothing was cited, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864. Unfortunately the `.log` info produced by `texify` is not very helpful. In any case you need to run Biber on your document and not BibTeX.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: I looked into it more, and I am still getting errors. What would you recommend here?

Comment: To get to the bottom of the errors, do not use `texify`. Run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX *manually* (best would even be from the command line/console/terminal if you are comfortable with that; assuming your `.tex` document is called `test.tex` you need to run `pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test` in that order). Before you do that delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...). If you managed to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX without error upload the `.log` and `.blg` files. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864

Comment: I got an error. I ran from commandline: `C:\Users\Ryan Schiller\Documents>pdflatex "try it".tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)

("try it.tex"
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
No file "try it".aux.
No file "try it".bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

("try it.aux")

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "try it"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on "try it.log".

Comment: I couldn't fit the entire command

Comment: Avoid spaces in file names.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

(tryit.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                tryit
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tryit.log.

Comment: I agree with egreg that a file name without spaces would be nicer. You can make things easier to read by adding the log output to your question directly. Anyway, so far you only showed the output of a `pdflatex` run. If this was only the first run everything is OK. Did you run `biber "try it"` as well followed by two more `pdflatex "try it"`s? What did the `.blg` say?

Comment: If you read my last attempt, I removed the space.

Answer (score 0):

I was mixing up Biber and Bibtex. I also didn't have keys for my sources.

Comment: For empty entry keys, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457685/35864

Comment: sorry to disappoint you guys. I just had to change syntax and use biber. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: For texify see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69705/35864