# Empty bibliography on input line!

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I was trying to make the first quote when I noticed the error "Empty bibliography on input line!" that since I left the file `.bib` empty, seemed normal to me. But since I entered references on the file, this error keeps popping up.

This is the project I’m working on:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
    
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{mybib.bib}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \input{Title}
    \clearpage
    \input{Abstract}
    \clearpage
    \input{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \clearpage
    \input{Coclusion}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Coclusion}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

and this is the bibliography:

```
    @book{,
      title= {The Post-traumatic Vegetative State.},
      author= {Giuliano Dolce, M.D.,Leon Sazbon, M.D,},
      year= {2002},
      isbn={3131300713}
      publisher= {Thieme},
      keywords = {PT-VS}
    }
```

Overleaf gave me the following errors:

The file '/compile/output. Bcf' contains no citations!
Empty bibliography on input line 22.

Comment: An entry key as in `@book{,` would be invalid. You need to give your reference a name like `@book{dolce,`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457685/35864. Additionally, the name field is not formatted correctly. Degrees and titles are generally not given in name fields, so you would drop the `M.D.`. Regardless of the desired output names must be separated with `and`. So `author= {Giuliano Dolce, M.D.,Leon Sazbon, M.D,},` should be `author= {Giuliano Dolce and Leon Sazbon},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: You're also missing a comma after the isbn entry.

Comment: Your ISBN is a little wonky altogether. It should be either 3-13-130071-X or **978**-3-13-130071-3. (Yes, dashes or other delimiters are significant.)