# Which characters are valid for bibliography entry identifiers?

Tags: biblatex, biber, characters, bibentry

I'm currently writing a paper for my study on the applicability of Spring Batch (a java framework) for the use cases of the department I'm currently in.

For this, I'm citing parts of the Spring documentation, and I wanted to use a `.` in the bibliography entry identifier. While this at first had me worried that dots might not be permitted in identifiers, it turns out they are.

However, I can't help but wonder which characters *are* permitted - is it ASCII characters? A subset of ASCII characters (i.e. alphanumeric, `.`, `-` and `_`)? All unicode characters? Some unicode characters?
Also, even if they are valid, are there characters that could create strange errors depending on which context the bibliography entry is referenced in?

No worries, I don't intend to use emojis in my identifiers, I'm just curious as to which characters are valid. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `.` is good, anything non-US-ASCII is risky if you use pdfLaTeX. A comma is out for obvious reasons, with Biber most brackets are also out. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243729/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388500/35864.

Comment: FWIW I usually stick to lowercase `a-z` (that way I don't have to remember capitalisation), digits, as well as few special characters that I deem safe, namely `.`, `:` and `-`. I can see why would want to use `_`, `+` in certain situations, but I would avoid most other ASCII special chars and definitely the non-ASCII range (even with the Unicode engines - what if I have to go back to pdfLaTeX?).

Comment: Thanks! Overall, your interpretation overlaps with my use so far - I've been mainly using letters and `:` so far (due to some advice I read at some point), but being a java developer, I figured that `.` would be more intuitive.

Comment: Is there anything left unclear after reading the linked questions? I.e. do you want an answer here or would you be OK with closing the question as a duplicate?

Comment: no, you can close it :)

Comment: Any favourite amongst the four suggestions?

Comment: @moewe [What is valid as a BibLaTeX entry key?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388500/what-is-valid-as-a-biblatex-entry-key)